# Installing older version of gcc using apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, aptitude

i am trying to install GCC version 3.2 using apt-get. But it complains the following

```
root@chid-VirtualBox:/home/chid/Downloads# apt-get install gcc=3.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.2' for 'gcc' was not found
```

I even tried with other version numbers found in the gcc website. But no luck. how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 2):

The version you want to install needs to exist in repositories you have in your apt sources (`/etc/apt` directory contains various apt settings including added repositories). You can add a repository that you know that has the version you're looking for (or a PPA if you're on Ubuntu-derived distro).

You need to find the repository on the internet that has the version of the package (in this case gcc 3.2) and it should contain a line like:

```
deb http://example.org/debian version foobar
```

You should add that line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then do:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install gcc=3.2
```

Then it will find GCC 3.2 in your newly added repository. However, do note that it will most likely overwrite system's version of GCC and that can cause all sorts of trouble and **is not advised unless you really know what you are doing** or the system is just a virtual machine for running that particular software you need to build.

You might also need to add the GPG key for the repository and the website containing the `sources.list` line will likely contain information about how to do so.

Comment: Can you provide those commands to do so?  This answer would be 100 times better if you did.

Comment: @Bojan: Thanks for your answer. But can you please be little more elaborate. I could hardly understand. I am not-so-linux guy. so zzZZZ....

Comment: @Bojan Markovic: can you please tell me how "to find the repository on the internet that has the version of the package"? EDIT: I need GCC 4.4.7 which was released on March 13, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

if you look for the package gcc you  will see that gcc version 4.7 comes with the distribution wheezy. You  have to use
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main

after the update, you do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```